# Consolidate VM Chain via VMware Lab Manager 4.0 SOAP API

Tags: vmware

I am searching for a way to consolidate the VM chain for a VMWare 4.0 library Configuration programmatically -
and I wonder why cloníng to workspace via API and deleting of the clone do not decrease the chain.

We have on basic library configuration and by cloning and deploying it to the workspace for IT-Tests the chain length grows. I thought of deleting the clone will decrease the chain, but it does not.

So has anyone found out how to consolidate the VM chain via API? Yes, it works when using the web interface.

Thanks and regards,

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use MachineConsolidate from the Internal API.

https://your.labmanager.server.com/LabManager/SOAP/LabManagerInternal.asmx?op=MachineConsolidate

VMWare doesn't officially support the internal API which is why you might not have seen it.  More information can be found here:

http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-10608